# Parse new URL into IFTTT

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, rss, ifttt

The RSS reader in IFTTT doesn't like `https://rss.art19.com/the-daily`. 
I am using python to extract a new link and `schedule` it for every morning at 06:30. I, however, find it extremely difficult to parse a new `url` into an IFTTT applet. I am using `glitch.com` to combine events.

The point is to automatically play this podcast at 06:30 on my Sonos setup.

```
import schedule
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def job():
    url = 'https://rss.art19.com/the-daily'
    request = requests.get(url)
    respose = request.content.decode('utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(respose, 'lxml')

    link = soup.find_all('enclosure')[0]

    a = str(link).split(' ')[3]
    x = slice(a)
    y = str(x).split('"')[1]

    print(y) 



# def notification(message):
#  report = {}
#  report[“value1”] = message
#  requests.post('https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/play_sonos/with/key/KEY", data=report')

# notification(number)

schedule.every().day.at("06:30").do(job,'It is 06:30am')
print('\n')
print(' Got it')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the `SOCO` Library.

```
from soco import SoCo
import schedule
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Play5
five_son = SoCo('PLAYER_IP')

#Play5(Office)
five_office_son = SoCo('PLAYER_IP')

#Play3
three_son = SoCo('PLAYER_IP')
print( 'Players are Active! ')
print('\n')


def get():
    url = 'https://rss.art19.com/the-daily'
    request = requests.get(url)
    respose = request.content.decode('utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(respose, 'lxml')

    link = soup.find_all('enclosure')[0]

    a = str(link).split(' ')[3]
    x = slice(a)
    y = str(x).split('"')[1]

    return y

def job():  
    sonos = five_office_son.partymode()
    sonos.play_uri(get())

    track = sonos.get_current_track_info()

    print(track)

    sonos.pause()
    sonos.play()


schedule.every().monday.at("06:30").do(job,'It is 06:30am')
schedule.every().tuesday.at("06:30").do(job,'It is 06:30am')
schedule.every().wednesday.at("06:30").do(job,'It is 06:30am')
schedule.every().thursday.at("06:30").do(job,'It is 06:30am')
schedule.every().friday.at("06:30").do(job,'It is 06:30am')
print('\n')
print('Got it')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60)
```